# System update notification but system already up-to-date

Tags: updates, operating-system, google-pixel

I've had the Google Pixel XL for over a year now (it's awesome) and I just received a notification to upgrade my OS to 8.1.0. Problem is, I already have 8.1.0 installed. I updated it a couple weeks ago. What is going on here?

This is also not the first time this has happened. I haven't been keeping track of when it's occured, but the same thing happened with 8.0.0 as well as a couple other times. Each time I've just went forward and reinstalled the udpate that I already had.

From what I can tell, there is no way to dismiss the notification and ignore the redundant update. I know that I could disable the system update notifications altogether, but I would like to have them, only just the first one.

This is not a major huge deal, but I'd be curious to know if people have thoughts about this. Thank you.

Comment: I don't own a Pixel, but are you sure it's the same update, instead of ones with the same Android version but newer monthly security patches?

Comment: Maybe a carrier specific update that comes with their bloat or add ons ? The first one is straight from Google and second is carrier is my *guess*. Otherwise it shouldn't alert

Comment: @AndyYan It has the identical version #, so I assumed it that same. Does Android put out security updates with the same version #? That would be odd, but I guess it could be that. Thanks!

Comment: @beeshyams I have Verizon and I don't think they have an OS version for the Pixel, but maybe: https://www.theverge.com/circuitbreaker/2016/10/12/13258286/verizon-google-pixel-fast-android-updates. Thanks for input!

Comment: You can always check with carrier !

Comment: That one you linked is 4 months old

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does Android put out security updates with the same version #?

Yes. Version number changes generally correspond with new features or new APIs. Occasionally it will also be incremented for major bugfixes, but this has been somewhat less common now that Google has tried to increase their release cadence (around Android 6.0-ish or so). Security updates will change the *build* number, but not the version number. See the list of [factory images](https://developers.google.com/android/images#marlin) for your device for an example of this (note all the repeated version numbers, followed by build IDs).

[image]

If you go to Settings > System > About phone you can find the "Android version" (circled blue below) and the "Build number" (circled red) of your current system. You can also check the "Android security patch level" on this screen to determine which security update you've received. They generally occur during the first week or so of each month, and they are outlined in the [monthly security bulletins](https://source.android.com/security/bulletin/). Most likely you're receiving a notification for the January security update.

[image]
<sup>Picture from https://wccftech.com/android-oreo-for-verizon-pixel/</sup>